# Collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute in datalist

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I am getting error when i try to fire event after clicking button which is outside datalist.

Error shows in for each statement :
 Collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute.

```
protected void btnSaveGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataListItem item in dlPl.Items)
        {            

                CommandEventArgs commandArgs = new CommandEventArgs("SaveGrid", btnSaveGrid);
                DataListCommandEventArgs repeaterArgs = new DataListCommandEventArgs(item,btnSaveGrid, commandArgs);
                dlPl_ItemCommand(btnSaveGrid, repeaterArgs);

       }



      protected void dlPl_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.CommandName == "SaveGrid")
                {
    //Some work
    }

}
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You may not modify the collection while you are enumerating it. dlPl_ItemCommand modifies dlPl.Items, which is not allowed.If you move DataBind outside the loop, it should work.

Comment: i tried to put outside loop but it shows error Error The name 'repeaterArgs' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Try to create a method get the list and bind inside the event